# How to export 15000+ Google Group members?

Tags: google-groups

There are around 15000+ members in my Google Group and I'd like to export them to a CSV file. Google Groups says there are too many to export. Is there any other way to export all the 15000+ members?

Comment: I struck out at both [the Data Liberation Front](http://www.dataliberation.org/) and [Google Takeout](http://www.google.com/takeout). Groups is one of those mostly neglected apps in Google's stable. Frankly, I fear for its longevity. I'm afraid that other than some sort of screen-scraper on your pages and pages of members you are probably out of luck.

Comment: @AlEverett I imagine that Google intends to replace Google Groups with Google+ Communities in the not-so-distant future